# Query SSIS metadata in over 200 packages deployed using package deployment for hard-coded connection to specific servers

Tags: sql-server, xml, ssis, ssis-2012

I am trying to ensure that copies of over 200 SSIS packages in SSIS 2012 that were deployed using package, not project, deployment do not have any design-time or hard-coded connections to certain servers. The configurations are handled using Config Tables, and I can check all of those, but how do I parse out the connection strings from the XML in the metadata? Please assume my knowledge of XML extends to being able to spell it. I am a T-SQL and C# developer but I never learned Xpath or DTD or any of those tools. I am getting the XML as varchar using a query someone else wrote, and I can search for the server name as a string, but that gives me lots of false-positives from descriptions or old packages with connection names that were too specific.
Did I add I have about 1/2 day to check all of these?
Joey

Comment: Might help if you post a sample of the query you are using, and the expected results. Or perhaps a sample of the XML to search in (with any private information or connection strings replaced with X's).